# SQL Server sometimes temporary partitions indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, partitioning, database-indexes

I have implemented a system on one of our SQL Servers (all currently 2008) that reads out the size and usage of indexes (not PKs) on our tables and stores the information historically in a dedicated database.

Each index gets a assigned a own SID in table a, and each time the index size or usage changes by a specified value a new entry in table b is created, the old one set to inactive (SCD2).
The jobs runs once a day.

Problem: On very rare occassions I get two rows of size for some indexes and so far it only has happened on 3 tables out of more than 1000 that are watched.

Where do i get the data:

```
        FROM IndexInfo.IndexOverview io
        JOIN IndexInfo.IndexSizeUsage isu ON io.IndexOverviewSid = isu.IndexOverviewSid
        JOIN XYZ.sys.partitions p ON io.object_id = p.object_id AND io.index_id = p.index_id
        JOIN ( SELECT container_id, SUM(total_pages) total_pages, SUM(used_pages) used_pages 
                 FROM XYZ.sys.allocation_units 
             GROUP BY container_id) a ON p.partition_id= a.container_id
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT object_id, index_id, ISNULL(100.0*(user_lookups+user_scans+user_seeks)
                                             / NULLIF((SELECT SUM(user_lookups+user_scans+user_seeks) 
                                                         FROM XYZ.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats indusinner
                                                        WHERE indusinner.database_id=indusout.database_id AND indusinner.object_id=indusout.object_id
                                                     GROUP by object_id),0),0) usage 
                    FROM XYZ.sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats indusout WHERE database_id=DB_ID('XYZ')) usageselect ON io.object_id=usageselect.object_id AND io.index_id=usageselect.index_id
```

This is is the important part.
IndexOverview (table a): one entry per created user index
IndexSizeUsage (table b): SCD2 data for usage and index size (by the time the error occurs only 1 active entry for each index)

The result:
Two rows in table b for an entry in table a while the only difference in the rows is the information from table a. As table a is Grouped by the only value I use for the join, SQL Server somehow creates a second partition by the time the data is read.

I tried to replicate the problem by manually executing this query while reorganizing / rebuilding the index (which should never happen by the time the job is scheduled) and by doing large inserts, forcing the index to grow.

When and why does SQL Server temporarily create a second partition?

Comment: I forgot additional information which might be useful: One of the 3 tables is the largest we have. It contains 186.658.181 rows, exists on 4 seperate sql instances.. yet the error happened only on two of them (till now). The indexes have filters on them.